# How would I create a session in a PHP class?

Tags: php, oop, session

I'm trying to start a session in one class, and assign various values.
In the next class I'm trying to obtain the results of that session?
But it's not working what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible to say for sure without code of course, but most common error is forgetting to start your code with:

`session_start()`

Keep [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) in mind: (as hinted in the comments by @julioc )

> To use cookie-based sessions,
>   session_start() must be called before
>   outputing anything to the browser.

Comment: Also make sure that the same session ID is going back and forth in the cookie headers on each request. If the ID isn't "sticking", you'd see session variables "disappearing", because each request is getting a different (fresh/clean/virgin) session instead of loading up the original one.

Comment: But that's not really common, right? (If so, I need to read up on that, because I wouldn't know how to 'fight' that :)  )

Comment: And make sure you´re are not sending any output before invoking session_start()

Comment: $_SESSION is a super global right? so I can call it in any Class and say print a value and it would print?

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, it's available throughout PHP in all scopes.

Comment: @Nanne: Generally it happens when you roll your own session handler and mis-configure the session cookie with `setcookie()`

Comment: I've got one class setting the session and another class echoing $_SESSION[1]; but it will say undefined variable?

Comment: @Matthew it's a superglobal - the same variable is automatically visible everywhere in a PHP script.

Comment: @Marc-B: ah, check. That's no worries here I think.  @matthew: do you call `session_start()` in *BOTH* classes? And how about if you test it with a string like most code does, like $_SESSION['yourVar']?